# How to read the position of items in a ScrollView in SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, scrollview

I'm trying to make an activity where a scroll view is created with a list of boxes with dialogue. I want to users to be able to move those dialogue boxes in the order in which they think is correct. I have coded the movement/reordering part already. I am having trouble with understanding how I can read the current positions of my items in the scroll view.

The dialogue boxes of the scroll view have 2 attributes, their text to display on the screen and also their correct position in the full dialogue.

So I want to be able to look at the order the user put things in and see if it matches the correct order they should be in.
Something along the lines of

if currentPosition/IndexOfItemInScrollView != item.itsCorrectPosition {
is wrong
}

This is my code so far

```
import SwiftUI


struct LAPutDialogueInOrder: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var listeningActivityManager: ListeningActivityManager
    
    @ObservedObject var ListeningActivityQuestionsVM: ListeningActivityQuestionsViewModel

    @State var draggingItem: dialogueBox?
    
    @StateObject var LAPutDialogueInOrderVM: LAPutDialogueInOrderViewModel
    
    @State var isUpdating = false
    let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 45), count: 1)
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ScrollView{
                
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20, content: {
                    ForEach(LAPutDialogueInOrderVM.dialogueBoxes){ item in
                        
                        dialogueBoxView(dialogueText: item.dialogueText)
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 60)
                            .background(.teal)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .shadow(radius: 10)
                            .opacity(item.id == draggingItem?.id && isUpdating ? 0.5 : 1) // <- HERE
                            .onDrag {
                                draggingItem = item
                                return NSItemProvider(contentsOf: URL(string: "\(item.id)"))!
                            }
                            .onDrop(of: [.item], delegate: DropViewDelegate(currentItem: item, items: $LAPutDialogueInOrderVM.dialogueBoxes, draggingItem: $draggingItem, updating: $isUpdating))
                    }
                }).animation(.default, value: LAPutDialogueInOrderVM.dialogueBoxes)
                
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                }, label: {
                    Text("test")})
                
                
            }.scrollDisabled(true)
                    
            
        }
    }
}
                   
    

struct dialogueBoxView: View {

    var dialogueText: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(dialogueText)
            .font(Font.custom("Chalkboard SE", size: 12))
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    }
}




struct LAPutDialogueInOrder_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static let ListeningActivityQuestionsVM = ListeningActivityQuestionsViewModel(dialogueQuestionView: dialogueViewObject(fillInDialogueQuestionElement: ListeningActivityElement.pastaCarbonara.fillInDialogueQuestion))
    static let LAPutDialogueInOrderVM = LAPutDialogueInOrderViewModel(dialoguePutInOrderVM: dialoguePutInOrderObj(stringArray: ListeningActivityElement.pastaCarbonara.putInOrderDialogueBoxes[0].fullSentences))
    static var previews: some View {
        LAPutDialogueInOrder(ListeningActivityQuestionsVM: ListeningActivityQuestionsVM, LAPutDialogueInOrderVM: LAPutDialogueInOrderVM)
            .environmentObject(ListeningActivityManager())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer my question but it turns out that in my DropDelegate class, the drop event was actually rearranging my array so all I needed to do was read my published array holding my items and they were in the current order the user put them in. Then I could just run a check against the index of the array and the correct position marked on my dialogue object